# Name.com naked domain to www

Tags: dns, pythonanywhere

I have a domain bought on name.com and a hacker plan on pythonanywhere. The webapp on pythonanywhere starts with www before the domain, so I need to redirect traffic going to the naked domain (petdb.live) to [www.petdb.live](http://www.petdb.live), but the docs on pythonanywhere doesn't have a name.com example.

I've already tried url redirect but it shows a coming soon page.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I saw that a lot of people use http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect literally after posting this.